# Get Element By Xpath (Geb)

Tags: selenium, groovy, spock, geb

I have problem with getting Element by Xpath. I use Spock with Geb.
I have HTML:

```
<form class="form" style="display: block;">
<div class="crm-field">
<div class="req label">
<span class="required">*</span>
Моё Имя:
</div>
<div class="value">
<input class="signup" type="text" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
</div>
</div>

<div class="crm-field">
<div class="req label">
<span class="required">*</span>
Login:
</div>
<div class="value">
<input class="signup" type="text" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
</div>
</div>

<div class="crm-field">
<div class="req label">
<span class="required">*</span>
Мой E-mail:
</div>
<div class="value">
<input class="signup" type="text" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
</div>
</div>

<div class="crm-field">
<div class="req label">
<span class="required">*</span>
Пароль:
</div>
<div class="value">
<input class="signup" type="text" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
</div>
</div>
```

I need get `<input class="signup" type="text" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">` for write string. But Geb use only CSS search.
Please help my get all input and how i can write text to input.

I use for getting element:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[2]/input")) << arg
```

But I did not get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geb doesn't support XPath expressions but you can still get the elements you need using Geb's [indexed css selectors](http://www.gebish.org/manual/snapshot/navigator.html#indexes_and_ranges). Please note that those indexes are 0 based in contrary to XPath's 1 based indexes. For example:

```
$('form.form > div', 1).find('input')
```

**EDIT**

Actually, Geb now [supports XPath expressions](http://www.gebish.org/manual/snapshot/navigator.html#using_webdrivers_by_class_selectors). Bear in mind that it has not yet been released and is only available in the latest snapshot, `0.10.1-SNAPHOT`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made clear **which** one you need, since they are all similar. However, in cases like this, work in a slightly different way than positional XPath.

That means, get something that close to what you need, and move about the DOM around that.

For instance, if you need the `input` need the `Email` label (presumably to type in the Email). You would first get the `Email` label (it's **near** what you need):

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Email')]
```

You'd then get the `div` **next door** to this, that is, the `div` directly after this one, making this query:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Email')]/following-sibling:div
```

You've then be able to say, well I want the `input` inside this `div`, so it becomes:

```
//div[contains(text(), 'Email')]/following-sibling:div/input[@type='text']
```

You then have uniquely identified the `input` element, where you can enter in the `Email`.